# Fill matrix per cell definition

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, grid

I need to show and edit my data in a view like matrix. All the data will be collected in a `ObserverableCollection`. Then i will fill the collection per cell definition. Each cell definition has the key of it's row and column, and a string, which should be shown in the matrix.

```
public class CellViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public object RowKey { get; set; }    
    public object ColumnKey { get; set; }
    public string CellText { get; set; }
}
```

That means, when a `CellViewModel` is added to the collection, and a row with same RowKey is already existed, the cell will be filled to suitable column of this row. If the column is not existed, a new column will be added. The key could be any object, with that man can add a cell with any object keys and don't need to care about setting right position of cell. For example, i fill the collection with `CellViewModels`:

```
GridCellViewModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<CellViewModel>
{
    new CellViewModel
    {
        RowKey = 1,
        ColumnKey = 1,
        CellText = "Cell1_1"
    },
    new CellViewModel
    {
        RowKey = "string",
        ColumnKey = 'char',
        CellText = "Cell2_2"
    },
    new CellViewModel
    {
        RowKey = 3,
        ColumnKey = 1,
        CellText = "Cell3_1"
    },
    new CellViewModel
    {
        RowKey = 1,
        ColumnKey = 3,
        CellText = "Cell1_3"
    },
    new CellViewModel
    {
        RowKey = 3,
        ColumnKey = 'char',
        CellText = "Cell3_2"
    }
}
```

Then the matrix should look like that:

```
        column1 column2 column3
row1    Cell1_1         Cell1_3
row2            Cell2_2
row3    Cell3_1 Cell3_2
```

I have tried with ItemsControl and convert the whole collection to suit the ItemsControl with place-holder...

```
var list = new List<CellViewModel>{ null, null, cellViewModel };
```

But I think that is not a good idea. And the place-holder will not reserve the place to hold the whole matrix in good order. Besides ItemsControl has no header for rows and columns.

Any idea or suggestion? With which control should I do that?

Comment: Did you consider using a Grid as ItemsPanel in the ItemsControl?

Comment: @Clemens: i have no idea. I have tried Grid withoud ItemsControl and GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Grid as ItemsPanel in your ItemsControl, and bind the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties in a Style in `ItemContainerStyle`. Of course column and row indices are zero-based.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GridCellViewModelCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid IsItemsHost="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnKey}"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowKey}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CellText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks! But have defined ColumnKey and RowKey with objects. That will be used to add new ViewModel with any objects as keys. That will not suit to Grid.Column or Grid.Row. And i still don't know how to show headers of rows and columns correctly, except add dummy cells...

Comment: You may use a binding converter to get integer row and column index from objects in RowKey and ColumnKey. Headers may be added externally, e.g. by putting the ItemsControl in an outer Grid.

Comment: I tried another way to show my data in ItemsControls. Headers are always problem. That will not hold the same level, if i use DataTemplate for my cell. It seems not easy to be solved.

Comment: How can i binding the width of header with the greatest width in it's column? I have tried to do that, but can not get it. That is the code in xaml:  Width="{Binding CellWidth, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  . I define the CellWidth as double, but got only NaN.