# Adding different user controls to a grid in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have, till now, five different UserControls and the number can increase in future. I want to add them to a grid using MVVM pattern.

I have a class **Apparatus** that could serve as a viewModel for the UserControl

```
public class Apparatus 
{
    private string _appratusName;
    private string _imageSource;
    private string _experiments;
    private GridProperties gridProps;

    public Apparatus()
    {
        _appratusName = "";
        _imageSource = "";
        Experiments = "";
    }

    public Apparatus(string name, string imgSource, string exp)
    {
        _appratusName = name;
        _imageSource = imgSource;
        _experiments = exp;

    }}
```

GridProperties is another class for containing the position of the UserControls in a grid.

```
public class GridProperties
{
    public int Row;

    public int Column;

    public int ColumnSpan;

    public int RowSpan;

    public GridProperties(int row, int col, int rowSpan, int columnSpan)
    {
        this.Row = row;
        this.Column = col;
        this.RowSpan = rowSpan;
        this.ColumnSpan = columnSpan;
    }
```

**there are public properties for each of the fields in the classes.**

and also there's a **ExperimentGridViewModel** that's like

```
    public class ExperimentGridViewModel : ViewModelBaseClass
{
    private int _apparatusCount;
    private string _workingExperiment;
    private int _gridRowCount;
    private int _gridColumnCount;
    private ExperimentWindowViewModel _windowModel;

    private ObservableCollection<Apparatus> _apparatusAppplied;}
```

I want to add UserControls, that are basically apparatuses like Burette, pippete etc. using MVVM.

I've looked though some answers for this and found out that this can be done using **DataTemplates and ItemsControl** but the problem is I have only one data type i.e **Apparatus** for all of my UserControls, Do I need to create different classes for each user control or Is there something else that I can do.

Now all I can do is some thing like this.

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Apparatus }">
            <apparatuses:Burette></apparatuses:Burette>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AppliedApparatus}" >

    </ItemsControl>
```

This adds burettes to grid, I can't add anything else as everything apparatus is of Type **Appatatus**.

Also, can any one please show me how could I bind the GridProperties in my viewModel to the the attached grid properties of the UserControls.

Comment: Either you create different view model classes - all derived from Apparatus - for which you could declare different DataTemplates, or you use a DataTemplateSelector (i.e. set the ItemsControl's ItemTemplateSelector property).

Comment: Okay I will try this, but can you help me in binding the <apparatus:Burette>'s Grid.Column value to GridProperty.Column that's present in Apparatus class.

Comment: Are the `UserControl` objects actually different types depending on the `Apparatus` instance? If not, you don't need to declare different classes for the view models, nor use `DataTemplateSelector`. As far as the above, the biggest thing that seems out of place is the use of `private` fields where one would normally use `public` properties (for binding). But without a clear problem statement and [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces that problem, it's impossible to know for sure what exactly you're asking, never mind answer.

Comment: I stated in the question itself that there are public properties for each field in the classes, I didn't include them as it would unnecessarily fill the space and yes the user control are of different types.

Comment: This is very easy to do with data triggers, just add a style to your UserControl and add a seperate datatrigger for each apparatus type which sets the Template property accordingly.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22201254/1136211) for an ItemContainerStyle that binds the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties.